# Bootstrap layout broken with margin in rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to create layouts in Bootstrap I ended up finding a problem not easy to solve. I'm trying to make a row with nested rows, but with a spacing between them. Without spacing the layout is beauty, but when you add the margin layout break!

**What I'm trying to do:**

[image]

**The result I got in my attempts:**

```
   <div class="block">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="block_header">
                <b>Núcleo Regional da Diretoria de Araguaína</b><br>
                (mock,  mock,  mock,  mock,  mock,  mock,  mock)
            </div>

            <div class="block_subheader">
                <b>Plantão</b>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-4 info">
                Defensor Público:<br>
                <b>Fabricio Silva Brito</b><br>
                Servidor:<br>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 info">
                Período                
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 info">
                Telefone
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 info">
                Início 07/03 as 18h00<br>
                Término 07/03 as 18h00
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 info">
                (92) 3232-3232
            </div> 

        </div>




    </div>
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/ywJ7k/1/

how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use a table, Then You'll adapt the space with `cellspacing` in the HTML. But you need to change all your HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="3">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">Plantão</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
        Defensor Público:<br>
                <b>Fabricio Silva Brito</b><br>
                Servidor:<br>
    </td>
    <td>Período</td>
    <td>Telefone</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        Início 07/03 as 18h00<br>
        Término 07/03 as 18h00
    </td>
    <td>
        (92) 3232-3232
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can see [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kr5e8/) for example.

I hope it'll help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with Bootstraps grid system, but there are some rules you have to take care of. One row in the grid system consists of 12 columns. If content exceeds 12 the layout is floating what means the block starts in the next line.

According to your first screenshot I would suggest a markup like this. Your first two columns should span the whole row (12), then divide 1:2 (4:8) where the 8 columns have a new row inside to hold the 4 informational blocks:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 block_header">
             <b>Núcleo Regional da Diretoria de Araguaína</b><br>
             (mock,  mock,  mock,  mock,  mock,  mock,  mock)
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 block_subheader">
             <b>Plantão</b>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 info">
             Defensor Público:<br>
             <b>Fabricio Silva Brito</b><br>
             Servidor:<br>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 info">
                    Período                
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 info">
                    Telefone
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 info">
                    Início 07/03 as 18h00<br>
                    Término 07/03 as 18h00
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 info">
                    (92) 3232-3232
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```